# Prove $ \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{(2k)!(2n-2k)!}{2^{2n}(2k+1)[k!(n-k)!]^{2}} = \frac{[2^{n}n!]^{2}}{(2n+1)!} $ using mathematical induction

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, discrete-mathematics, induction

I want to show the following equality:

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{(2k)!(2n-2k)!}{2^{2n}(2k+1)[k!(n-k)!]^{2}} = \frac{[2^{n}n!]^{2}}{(2n+1)!}
$$

Since I already know the way using combinatorial proof, I am trying to prove it by **mathematical induction** but it is not easy to show.

I derived that
$$ S_{n} = \frac{2n}{2n+1}S_{n-1} $$ from RHS,
but how can I proceed from this? I mean, how can I organize the LHS?
I cannot organize LHS properly because of different n, n = m & n = m + 1. (Adjusting k was not very effective.)

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

*HINT*. First of all notice that:
$$
(2n+1)! = 1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot \ldots \cdot 2n \cdot (2n+1) = [1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot \ldots \cdot (2n+1)] \cdot 2^n [1 \cdot 2 \cdot \ldots \cdot n] = (2n+1)!! \cdot 2^n \cdot n!
$$

*HINT 2*. Based on the first hint, you want to prove that:

$$
S_n = \dfrac{[2^n n!]^2}{(2n+1)!} = \dfrac{2^n n!}{(2n+1)!!} 
$$

*HINT 3*. What does the second hint and the rule: $S_n = \dfrac{2n}{2n+1} S_{n-1}$ have in common?

Comment: Can you explain more steps? I cannot proceed from that..